# time limit exceeded in GAMS

Tags: integer, cplex, gams-math

I write my MIP model in GMAS, and the solver indicates that there are 1535272 rows, 3287490 columns, and 8425140 nonzeros in my model(I'm not sure if it is too big for GAMS). After 899677 iterations(1:26:36 running time), GAMS shows

RESOURCE USAGE, LIMIT       1084.469      1000.000
ITERATION COUNT, LIMIT    900026    2000000000

MIP status(108): time limit exceeded, no integer solution
Cplex Time: 1002.13sec (det. 849920.06 ticks)
CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists.
Resource limit exceeded, no integer solution found.
My PC has i7-8700 CPU @ 3.2GHZ and 32 RAM(has not been used up when calculation stop). How can I deal with this problem, or is it too big for GAMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, GAMS sets a time limit of 1000 seconds for a solve statement. You can increase this by changing the [reslim](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_GamsCall.html#GAMSAOResLim) option. There are three ways to do this (e.g. to set it to 3600 seconds):

1. On the command line when calling GAMS: gams  resLim=3600
2. Using an option statement inside your model (influences all following solve statements): option resLim=3600;
3. Using a modelAttribute inside your model (influences all following solve statements for that particular model): modelName.resLim=3600;

Hope that helps,
Lutz

Comment: @JiaweiLu: It sounds like this answer solves your problem. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer so that others know the issue is resolved.